# Converting android app to ios (obj c)

Tags: ios, objective-c

I want any android  app converted to ios (obj c). Is it possible?
If yes how can I do this?

Comment: This isn't quite a programming question, is it? Have you googled for it already?

Comment: ya. It's not directly related to programming. I have googled for it. I found this link https://github.com/tomball/j2objc-sample-reversi . But it's not working. :(

Comment: It is throwing an error "J2OBJC_HOME not correctly defined in LibConfig.xcconfig". Can't solve the error.

Comment: that means you havent set the J2OBJC_HOME variable correctly. you can do this via the Terminal. look up how to set environment variable.

Answer (score 0):

It depends if application is written in pure Java? If not consider usage of tools like Xamarin.